# How to usb-serial in Sonoma?

Tags: macos, usb, sonoma

Last time I could work with usb-serial port on Mac OS Sonoma.

Then, after a probably update, the serial port dissapered and I couldn't find a new one. I´ve tried several solutions, no one was running, downloading FTDI driver from FTDI chip and installing were not successful, so now I cant work with my hardware anymore. Silabs CP210x USB to UART Bridge Driver was not working as well, it installed successfully but created no usbserial device

Besides the fact that it is very dangerous in trying "something" on the system, installing drivers, gibe them access to the system, I would predicated and usbserial solution from Apple.

Is there a possibility to get a usbserial driver for Sonoma?

Comment: Same here. For kernel extensions to work, you have to enable them (via System Settings and boot into restore), not something I want to do. So the only other solution I found so far: Use a virtual Linux (or Win) e.g. with Parallels, install the drivers and do the work there. Not very nice, hopefully, there will eventually be a driver solution which is userspace only and doesn't require kernel extensions at all.

Answer (score 1):

I was attempting to program an ESP32-CAM via FTDI on OSX Sonoma on an M1 Macbook.  Took a while, but eventually figured it out and got my FTDI serial port to show up in the Arduino IDE.

1. Modify your security settings to be more permissive -- no need to allow remote management of kernel extensions, but do need to allow signed drivers.
2. Download the FTDI chip driver from here: https://ftdichip.com/drivers/vcp-drivers/   Note that you want to download 1.5.0 DMG for ARM.
3. Extract the downloaded installer and copy the `FTDIUSBSerialDextInstaller_1_5_0` application to your /Applications/ directory.
4. Run it, click "Install", and it should load properly.  If you have any permissions that you need to enable in your OSX Settings, then go there and approve them.

Once this was done, this was enough for me to see /dev/cu.usbserial-B00055E0 show up in my Arduino IDE ports list.